# A function that will play two hands of five cards?

Tags: c

In a program that shuffles a deck of cards, I am trying to write a function that plays two hands of said cards.

Here is the gist:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ab16041559c72657832f

The prototype is on line 23 and the function I have so far begins on 133. 
The program compiles and runs, but when I try to write in a printf function to output the results it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not calling `PlayHands`

By the way, `PlayHands` appears to copy 5 properties for each card that it moves from the deck to a player's hand. But cards have only <s>three</s> two properties! (note that `NPROPS` is defined as 2)

I would strongly recommend you use a struct instead.

For example:

```
struct Card {
    int suit;
    int value;
};
```

Comment: Wow major lapse there -.- thanks. Should I call it right after PrintCard on line 46? It would look like this right : PlayHands(H1,H2);

Comment: My instructor asked that we not use structs yet since we have not gotten to that part of the lesson plan yet

Comment: You should try it and see what happens. I'm sure you'll get it working if you keep at it.